# Merge / Apend two YAML files

Tags: merge, yaml, append, yq

Let's assume that you want to inject an extra container to all the Pods submitted to the cluster.

You could save the YAML configuration for the extra container as a YAML file called file:

fileA:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envoy-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: proxy-container
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.12.2
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

and you have fileB

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    env:
    - name: DB_URL
      value: postgres://db_url:5432
```

The output should be

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    env:
    - name: DB_URL
      value: postgres://db_url:5432
  - name: proxy-container
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.12.2
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

This was possible in the older version of yq by

`yq m -a append fileA.yaml fileB.yaml`

However, this appears not possible in v4 - any suggestions?

Comment: jq? Don't you mean yq?

Comment: @knittl yes yq - that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the [merge/append operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#multiply-merge) `*+`:

```bash
yq '. *+ load("fileB.yaml")' fileA.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: proxy-container
      image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.12.2
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      env:
        - name: DB_URL
          value: postgres://db_url:5432
```

Answer (score 0):

gojq won't retain the original ordering of keys, but if that is not a concern you could go with:

```
gojq --yaml-output --yaml-input '.spec.containers += input.spec.containers'  y2.yaml y1.yaml
```